# How to convert this promise object into an array with the result

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rest, react-native

So I'm calling the tmdb API to get the movie details of the selected movie but that response does not contain the cast details like the actors so i use the id returned by the first response to call their other api to get the details of the cast.

**This is the action**

```js
export const loadNewReleases = () => {
  const posterBaseUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";
  let hasUserSaved;
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    // console.log("", getState());
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=${config.TMDB_API_KEY}`
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("failed response");
      }

      const resData = await response.json();
      console.log(resData);

      const getCredits = async (index) => {
        let response, creditsData;
        try {
          response = await fetch(
            `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${resData.results[index].id}?api_key=${config.TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US&append_to_response=credits`
          );
          creditsData = await response.json();
          // console.log("credits", creditsData);
        } catch (err) {
          throw new Error(err);
        }

        const castMembers = [];
        const length = creditsData.credits.cast.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          castMembers.push(
            new Cast(
              creditsData.credits.cast[i].id,
              creditsData.credits.cast[i].character,
              creditsData.credits.cast[i].name,
              posterBaseUrl + creditsData.credits.cast[i].profile_path
            )
          );
        }

        console.log(castMembers);

        return castMembers;
      };

      const LoadedNewReleases = [];
      const length = resData.results.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // let credits;
        hasUserSaved = getState().UserMovies.userMovies.find(
          (userMovie) => userMovie.id === resData.results[i].id.toString()
        );
        // let cast = getCredits(i).then((cast) => cast);
        // console.log("CAST", cast);
        LoadedNewReleases.push(
          new Movie(
            resData.results[i].id.toString(),
            resData.results[i].media_type === "movie"
              ? resData.results[i].title
              : resData.results[i].name,
            posterBaseUrl + resData.results[i].poster_path,
            resData.results[i].media_type === "movie"
              ? resData.results[i].release_date
              : resData.results[i].first_air_date,
            getCredits(i).then((cast) => cast),
            // cast,
            resData.results[i].overview,
            resData.results[i].vote_average,
            "",
            hasUserSaved ? hasUserSaved.location : ""
          )
        );
      }

      dispatch({ type: LOAD_NEW_RELEASES, new_releases: LoadedNewReleases });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
};
```

**This is the reducer**

```js
switch(action.type){

    case LOAD_NEW_RELEASES:
      return {
        ...state,
        new_releases: action.new_releases,
      };

}
```

This is How I dispatch the action: **selectedMovie.cast**

```js
     selectedMovie = movies.find((movie) => movie.id === selectedMovieId);
    console.log("selectedMovie", selectedMovie);

        <FlatList
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          horizontal={true}
          data={selectedMovie.cast}
          renderItem={(itemData) => (
            <CastMember
              castName={itemData.item.name}
              posterUrl={itemData.item.profileUrl}
              character={itemData.item.character}
            />
          )}
        />
```

This is the log

On Loading the app 
I get the following yellow warnings

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'creditsData.credits.cast')]
>   * store/actions/MoviesAction.js:77:25 in getCredits
>   - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
>   - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:30 in invoke
>   - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
>   - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
>   - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:145:19 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
>   - node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
>   - node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates
>   * [native code]:null in callImmediates
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0
>   * [native code]:null in flushedQueue
>   * [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
>
> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'creditsData.credits.cast')]
>   * store/actions/MoviesAction.js:77:25 in getCredits
>   - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
>   - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:30 in invoke
>   - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
>   - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
>   - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:145:19 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
>   - node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
>   - node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates
>   * [native code]:null in callImmediates
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0
>   * [native code]:null in flushedQueue
>   * [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

and in dispatching the said action
I get :

```
selectedMovie Movie {
  "cast": Promise {
    "_40": 0,
    "_55": Array [
      Cast {
        "character": "Tim Morris",
        "id": 60950,
        "name": "David Spade",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Missy",
        "id": 591834,
        "name": "Lauren Lapkus",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Camille",
        "id": 175585,
        "name": "Candace Smith",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Julia",
        "id": 49001,
        "name": "Sarah Chalke",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Melissa",
        "id": 60952,
        "name": "Molly Sims",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Jack Winstone",
        "id": 25879,
        "name": "Geoff Pierson",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Nate",
        "id": 32907,
        "name": "Nick Swardson",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Jess",
        "id": 60959,
        "name": "Jackie Sandler",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Rich",
        "id": 1573273,
        "name": "Chris Witaske",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Vanilla Ice",
        "id": 17338,
        "name": "Vanilla Ice",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Calvin Sr.",
        "id": 5621,
        "name": "John Farley",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Bus Woman",
        "id": 1922821,
        "name": "Lori Pelenise Tuisano",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Komante",
        "id": 60949,
        "name": "Rob Schneider",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Gary",
        "id": 1170011,
        "name": "Leati Joseph Anoa'i",
      },
      Cast {
        "character": "Toki Dum Dum",
        "id": 198149,
        "name": "Bobby Lee",
      },
    ],
    "_65": 1,
    "_72": null,
  },
  "id": "582596",
  "language": "",
  "location": "",
  "plot": "A guy meets the woman of his dreams and invites her to his company's corporate retreat, but realizes he sent the invite to the wrong person.",
  "posterUrl": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/A2YlIrzypvhS3vTFMcDkG3xLvac.jpg",
  "ratings": 6.1,
  "title": "The Wrong Missy",
  "year": "2020-05-13",
}
```

See the cast object has a promise object and it has an array on _55 , that is the actual result.
Also What is causing the yellow warnings they appear only when i perform the second api call.

> > Snack Link

[Snack Link](https://snack.expo.io/@abhisheksah/6ae7a1)

> **when the app launches click on any of the items under trending> to see the log .**

Comment: Make a snack of the issue on expo and link it with the question.

Comment: added the link to the snack project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the line:

```
getCredits(i).then((cast) => cast)
```

You're not actually waiting for the result of this Promise, you're just passing in a Promise where a `cast` object should be.

You actually need to movie the creation of a `Movie` to the `then` call and then wait for all those to complete and unwrap them with `await` a [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) containing these new promises.

In the simplest way possible it'd be something like this:

```
const LoadedNewReleases = [];
const length = resData.results.length;

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  // let credits;
  hasUserSaved = getState().UserMovies.userMovies.find(
    (userMovie) => userMovie.id === resData.results[i].id.toString()
  );
  // let cast = getCredits(i).then((cast) => cast);
  // console.log("CAST", cast);
  LoadedNewReleases.push(
    getCredits(i).then(
      (cast) =>
        new Movie(
          resData.results[i].id.toString(),
          resData.results[i].media_type === "movie"
            ? resData.results[i].title
            : resData.results[i].name,
          posterBaseUrl + resData.results[i].poster_path,
          resData.results[i].media_type === "movie"
            ? resData.results[i].release_date
            : resData.results[i].first_air_date,
          cast,
          // cast,
          resData.results[i].overview,
          resData.results[i].vote_average,
          "",
          hasUserSaved ? hasUserSaved.location : ""
        )
    )
  );
}

dispatch({ type: LOAD_NEW_RELEASES, new_releases: await Promise.all(LoadedNewReleases) });
```

You may also want to move the `hasUserSaved` logic into there if you want that to run as late as possible, but I'm not quite sure what that's doing so have left it where it is.

Comment: actually this doesn't work because the cast object comes from the creditsData response object and the others come from the resData reponse object. can you think of any thing else ? it would be a great help , ive been stuck there for awhile .

Comment: There's no real reason this should't work. It's a question of merging the two response objects. The `cast` variable above is being taken from the result of `getCredits` (which _is_ the `creditsData` value), whereas the rest is being taken from `resData`.

Comment: it might not because i think the cast has to extracted into another object array because it has a different structure and is a big object of arrays.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're point (how it has to be extracted) is but I copy and pasted this change into your expo link and the app seems to run fine: https://snack.expo.io/unNYF6x0T

Comment: apart from the question , if i do selectedMovie.cast._55 , it works because the promise object has a _55 property that has the result , is it advised to follow this workaround ?

Comment: i works but the promise object is still a promise object. ```selectedMovie Movie {
  "cast": Promise {
    "_40": 0,
    "_55": Array [
      Cast {
        "character": "Tim Morris",
        "id": 60950,
        "name": "David Spade",
        "profileUrl": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/8tv638lAMLmYh8bSLICqPzbW3tv.jpg",
      },``` sort of like this